# How do the new Rocket League ranks match up to the old ranks?

Tags: rocket-league

The ranks in [Rocket League](https://www.rocketleague.com/news/rocket-league-free-to-play--seasons--new-ranks--and-more/) have changed slightly after going F2P:

> Changes aren't only happening at the top. We're working to soft reset the rest of the ranks to account for incoming players picking up Rocket League for the first time. This means Ranks will shift closer to the median Rank (close to Gold III). For instance, when current Bronze players complete their placement matches, they may be placed in a higher rank since they'll be better than new players who are just starting out.

I'm curious to know how the new Rocket League ranks match up to the old ranks? The article linked above doesn't specifically talk about how the ranks match up past to present.

Comment: I suspect it's because they don't know. They're just moving everyone closer towards Gold III, and letting the ELO system figure out who will return to their old rank.

Answer (score 2):

As they said: "Ranks will shift closer to the median Rank (close to Gold III)"
So I think that if you are a Platinum I, maybe you could be able to go easier to Platinum III or Diamond I.
As you could know, you can't forecast how many wins you have to get to advance your rank.
For example I was Platinum I/II before the update, now I'm Diamond III.

Comment: I thought it was the other way around. E.g. someone of a skill level that would formerly be ranked, say, Diamond I, would now be ranked Platinum II/III after the update. I don't have a reference for that, but it tracks with what I've observed. I highly doubt that your ranking up from PII to DIII is due to the update.